# SqlDataReader closed for unknown reason

Tags: c#, asp.net

C# noob here. I am trying to get some data from a SQL Data Base using the code below, however i get the error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.'

After searching for the answer online, i found nothing, maybe someone can see what is wrong?

The error happens at: while (rdr.Read())

Thank you!

```
internal List<string> GetInflationByYearData(string Country, int StartYear, 
int EndYear)
        {
            string CS = 
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SpCountryData", con)
                {
                    CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@act", 
"getInflationByYearData");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", Country);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startYear", StartYear);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endYear", EndYear);
                var table = new DataTable();
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    {
                        table.Load(rdr);
                    };
                }
                //con.Close();
                List<string> labelList = new List<string>();
                List<string> valueList = new List<string>();
                if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                    {
                        string label = row["Year"].ToString();
                        string value = row["Percentage"].ToString();
                        labelList.Add(label);
                        valueList.Add(value);
                    }
                }
                List<string> list = new List<string>();
                StringBuilder sbLabels = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (string lbl in labelList)
                {
                    sbLabels.Append(lbl + ",");
                }
                StringBuilder sbValues = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (string val in valueList)
                {
                    sbValues.Append(val + ",");
                }
                list.Add(sbLabels.ToString().Substring(0, sbLabels.Length - 
1));
                list.Add(sbValues.ToString().Substring(0, sbValues.Length - 
1));
                return list;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Load` consumes the reader to completion; you should **either** have a `while (rdr.Read())` loop, **or** call `table.Load(rdr)`, but: not both. `Load` basically does that same loop internally.

So: remove the loop - just use `Load`.

However! If all you want is the data as `List<string>`, loading it into a `DataTable` seems like an unnecessary step (`DataTable` is *not* lightweight) - it seems like you could do that *in the reader*, or perhaps use other tools (like "dapper") to remove that.

It isn't clear what data types `Year` and `Percentage` are, but as a "dapper" example...

```
class MyRowThing {
    public int Year {get;set;}
    public decimal Percentage {get;set;}
}

var rawData = con.Query<MyRowThing>("SpCountryData",
    new { // params here
        act = "getInflationByYearData", Country,
       startYear = StartYear, endYear = EndYear
    }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).AsList();

// now loop over rawData, which is a List<MyRowThing> with the data
```

Comment: Thank you, it works after I removed the loop. I had no ideea about the "Load" thing. This function should return a list of 2 strings that become dataset and labels for a Chart.js chart. This is the first time i hear of Dapper. It seems shorter and simpler. Thank you again, Marc! :)

Comment: @CristiPriciu "dapper" is the tool that we use (and wrote) here at Stack Overflow - it is designed to be very easy and obvious to use (unlike raw ADO.NET), *and* be very fast and efficient at execution :) - available on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/

Answer (score 2):

Replacing:

```
  var table = new DataTable();
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    {
                        table.Load(rdr);
                    };
                }
                //con.Close();
                List<string> labelList = new List<string>();
                List<string> valueList = new List<string>();
                if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                    {
                        string label = row["Year"].ToString();
                        string value = row["Percentage"].ToString();
                        labelList.Add(label);
                        valueList.Add(value);
                    }
                }
```

With:

```
    con.Open();

    List<string> labelList = new List<string>();
    List<string> valueList = new List<string>();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
            labelList.Add(rdr["Year"].ToString());
            valueList.Add(rdr["Percentage"].ToString());
    }
```

Will get rid of the `DataTable` for a more optimized code.